# How do you make it so on_reaction_add only triggers when it's the bot's message being reacted

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is the code I have now:

```py
# Reaction events
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.message.author == "Among Us Bot#3079":
        emoji = reaction.emoji
        if user.bot:
            return
        if emoji == '✅':
            fixed_channel = client.get_channel(742888039872856067) # General / main chat channel ID
            await fixed_channel.send(f'{user.mention} is ready to play! [{reaction.count - 1}/10]')
    else:
        print("BRUH")


@client.event
async def on_reaction_remove(reaction, user):
    if reaction.message.author == "Among Us Bot#3079":
        emoji = reaction.emoji
        if user.bot:
            return
        if emoji == '✅':
            fixed_channel = client.get_channel(742888039872856067) # General / main chat channel ID
            await fixed_channel.send(f'{user.mention} is no longer ready to play! [{reaction.count - 1}/10]')
    else:
        print("BRUH x2")
```

Right now, when you react to any message with the check, it prints  "BRUH" into the console. Before the `if reaction.message.author == "Among Us Bot#3079":` if there was a check reaction on any message, it would say "{user} is ready to play! [0/10]".

Comment: Change it to `if reaction.message.author.name == "Among Us Bot#3079":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reaction.message.author` is an object, however when it is converted to a string it outputs as the name of the user. Try using `if reaction.message.author.id == client.user.id` instead.